# Global inbox fails to show new answer on meta

Tags: bug, global-inbox, per-site-meta

The answer to [this question of mine](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13453/tags-for-questions-specific-to-decimal-notation) on meta.math.SE did not show up in my global inbox; I had to learn of it by chance.

I suspect this may be related to it being a meta site where reputation is not awarded, etc. etc. But I would still like to be notified when someone answers my question.